# Tool to chart Ethereum address over time

Tags: statistics

Is there a tool to chart the amount of Ether of a given address over time?

I'm looking for something similar to what Blockchain.info provides. (Example for the presale address [here](https://blockchain.info/charts/balance?address=36PrZ1KHYMpqSyAQXSG8VwbUiq2EogxLo2&timespan=2year).)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're asking for, but worth noting for future reference is the [statistics](https://live.ether.camp/account/267be1c1d684f78cb4f6a176c4911b741e4ffdc0/stat) view on [ether.camp](https://live.ether.camp/).

It won't give you the amount of ether, but does chart the number of different types of transactions over time for a given address.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an application with Web3.js that does this:
http://shawntabrizi.com/ethgraph/

You can find the source here:
https://github.com/shawntabrizi/ETH-Balance-Graph

[image]

Comment: website seems to be broken.

Comment: @Tank might have been a temporary thing. Looks like it is working for me.